# Broken phone with "Keychain is Not Accessible. SFMCSDK will Not initialize!"

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

We updated our iOS SFMC SDK and did a partial update where we first updated the SDK to 8.1.2 and only in a second build we fixed the dependency to https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-sdk-ios and updated it to 1.1.2.

Now we can't get SFMC to work on this device with the following errors:

```
Keychain Write Access Not Available, code: -25299
Keychain Write Access Not Available, code: -25299
Keychain Write Access Not Available, code: -25299
Keychain Write Access Not Available, code: -25299
Keychain Write Access Not Available, code: -25299
Keychain Write Access Not Available, code: -25299
Keychain is Not Accessible. SFMCSDK will Not initialize!
```

Uninstalling and reinstalling, reverting the version and so on does not resolve the problem.

Edit:
This is the code we use to initialize. At a minimum I would expect that `initializeSdk` is still called and my completion handler runs so I can react to the fact that the SDK is not working.

```swift
    // To override the Keychain accessibility attribute
    SFMCSdk.setKeychainAccessibleAttribute(
      accessibleAttribute: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlockedThisDeviceOnly)

    // Use the Mobile Push Config Builder to configure the Mobile Push Module. This gives you the maximum flexibility in SDK configuration.
    // The builder lets you configure the module parameters at runtime.
    let mobilePushConfiguration = PushConfigBuilder(appId: appId)
      .setAccessToken(accessToken)
      .setMarketingCloudServerUrl(appEndpoint)
      .setMid(mid)
      .setDelayRegistrationUntilContactKeyIsSet(delayRegistration)
      .setAnalyticsEnabled(analytics)
      .build()

    // Set the completion handler to take action when module initialization is completed. Result indicates if initialization was successful or not.
    let completionHandler: (OperationResult) -> Void = { initializeSuccess in
      if initializeSuccess == .success {
        // module is fully configured and is ready for use!
        self.setupMobilePush()
        result(true)
      } else if initializeSuccess == .error {
        // module failed to initialize, check logs for more details
        result(false)
      } else if initializeSuccess == .cancelled {
        // module initialization was cancelled (for example due to re-configuration triggered before init was completed)
        result(false)
      } else if initializeSuccess == .timeout {
        // module failed to initialize due to timeout, check logs for more details
        result(false)
      }
    }
      
      let config = ConfigBuilder().setPush(config: mobilePushConfiguration, onCompletion: completionHandler).build()

    // Once you've created the mobile push configuration, initialize the SDK.
    SFMCSdk.initializeSdk(config)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the error 25299 means that there is a duplicate item in the keychain.

I then ran this code once, which permanently resolved the issue for me:

```swift
 let secItemClasses =  [
      kSecClassGenericPassword,
      kSecClassInternetPassword,
      kSecClassCertificate,
      kSecClassKey,
      kSecClassIdentity,
    ]
    for itemClass in secItemClasses {
      let spec: NSDictionary = [kSecClass: itemClass]
      SecItemDelete(spec)
    }
```

Credits go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/53982755/3410232

I still consider this a bug in the SFMC iOS SDK.